# /usr/lib/libgraph.so.1 is not a symbolic link

Tags: kali-linux

I am getting this error/warning (whatever it is) after installing any software through apt-get install:

> Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.19-18) ...
>   /sbin/ldconfig.real: /usr/lib/libgraph.so.1 is not a symbolic link

How do I fix this?

I am using Kali 2.0.

This hasn't caused me any problems so far but I like to keep it clean ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hasn't caused me any problems so far

> *could be just a warning*

but I like to keep it clean ;)

> *can u try unlinking it?*

```
:-$ unlink /usr/lib/libEGL.so.1; ln -s libEGL.so /usr/lib/libEGL.so.1
```